# How to show image title if source image is not found using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I wanted to display the image title whenever the image is broken or the image is not found in the given path.

As of now I've options to hide the image and replace the image with the default image

```
$('img').on("error", function() {
  $(this).attr('src', '/images/missing.png');
});

// Or, hide them
$("img").on("error", function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

However, this is not satisfy my requirement. If anyone has a idea for displaying the image title when the image is broken using JavaScript or jQuery. Please help me with that.

Comment: where do you want to show the title

Comment: Use the 'alt' attribute to hold you description you want, it will display your message incase image isn't loaded due to some failure - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: Article written with ❤ by Ire Aderinokun : https://bitsofco.de/styling-broken-images/

Comment: thanks for sharing your ideas as comments , i have cracked it.  Thank you

Comment: if you'd like to consider a simple HTML/CSS solution check out this CodePen: https://codepen.io/aequalsb/pen/poPRdBo
basically... you can stylize an image with CSS as if it was a container... if the image is broken it looks like a regular "box"

Answer (score 1):

Replace your image tag with other elements using `replaceWith` inside error.

```js
$('img').on("error", function() {
  var title = $(this).prop("title");
  $(this).replaceWith("<span>" + title + "</span>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://stackoverflow.com/testimg.jpg" title="Your title"></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
   
   $("img").on("error", function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-bRgqJ3P_4k8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAjQ/eYIXbdyNxKM/photo.jpg?sz=48");
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Try jQuery Online</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body> 
 <img  
     src="/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-sl.jpg"
     alt="Grapefruit slice atop a pile of other slices">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this does not answer the OPs question... OP specifically asked how to show "image title"

Comment: Hi aequalsb,
As of now I've options to hide the image and replace the image with the default image

Comment: i don't understand... OP is asking how to "show the IMG TITLE" on images with broken links... NOT "replace with a default image" on images with broken links

Answer (score -1):

I have found an easy way to do this, only thing we need to do is to add the image into the Div, so that we can get the parent DIV Id of the image, and append the title to this parent div using the following code.

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].onerror = function() {
    $("#"+this.parentElement.id).append(this.title)
    this.style.display='none';
  }
}
```